# Copy rows in a table (to the same table), changing one column if a certain condition is met

Tags: plsql

Something like this:

(v_city, v_address v_name are already variables that I have already declared)

```
    insert into table1 (id, name, address, city)
    select table1_seq.nextval, name, address, city from table1 where city=v_city;
```

BUT I want the address to be changed to v_address if name=v_name.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
insert into table1 (id
                   ,name
                   ,address
                   ,city)
select table1_seq.nextval
      ,name
      ,case when name = v_name then v_address else address end
      ,city
from table1
where city = v_city;
```

Comment: Thanks. Easier than I thought